# How could I fix the wrong message "Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done"

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am using **keras_ocr on jupyter using VScode**. By running this code: prediction_groups = pipeline.recognize(images) I get this error message "How could I fix the wrong message "Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details."
can someone help me please to solve it

solving an issues of kernel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by **insufficient memory**. You can try to add the following code to your file:

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
```